# c++ std::intializer_list and constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, parameter-passing

Im trying to create a function that works with 'groups' of vectors.

Let the groups be named `A`, `B`, `C`, ... there may be any number of groups. Each group has one 'main' vector, eg. `v_A` of type `int` and a variable number of associated vectors, eg. `v_A1`, `v_A2`, ... all of type `float`.

I wish to create a function `groupwise` that may take a variable number of groups, each with a variable number of elements, as shown below.

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

struct group_t {
    vector<int> x;
    vector<vector<float>> vv;
    group_t(vector<int> x, std::initializer_list<vector<float>> lv) : x(x) { // constructor
        for (auto v : lv) {
            vv.push_back(v);
        }
    }
};

void groupwise(std::initializer_list<group_t> listofgroups) {}

int main() {
    vector<int> v_A, v_B, v_C;
    vector<float> v_A1, v_A2, v_B1, v_B2, v_B3, v_C1;

    groupwise( // No matching function for call to 'groupwise'
        { v_A, { v_A1, v_A2 } },
        { v_B, { v_B1, v_B2, v_B3} },
        { v_C, { v_C1 } }
    );
}
```

My idea here of nested initializer lists (if that is what i have made? ...) does not work. No matching function for call to `groupwise` is the compiler error I get.

How to achieve a correctly declared function `groupwise` that can be called in the simplest fashion? If possible, I would like to avoid having to construct each group of vectors explicitly before calling `groupwise` and would rather have that taken care of automatically in the call to `groupwise` (as I intended here via the constructor of `group_t`).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need another pair of braces in the function call to indicate the outermost `initializer_list`, like this:

```
groupwise({   // here
    { v_A, { v_A1, v_A2 } },
    { v_B, { v_B1, v_B2, v_B3} },
    { v_C, { v_C1 } }
});  // and here
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v6Yroq).

Comment: No problem :) Pretty soon you'll get used to these kinds of things and be able to spot it yourself :)

Comment: @zen Also, consider accepting the the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: cigien  i wanted to accept it right away but since that is not allowed, one gets distracted;-) btw whats up with the @ to people, sometimes you can use it, sometimes not?

Comment: @zen That's what I figured, so thought I'd make a reminder ;)

Comment: You can @ someone if they are part of the comment thread. You don't need to @ the person whose post you're commenting on though.

Comment: yeah but i wrote @ cigien without the space, and the whole thing gets omitted.. spooky. i have experienced that many times now. sometimes ok, sometimes not. must be a bug.

Comment: Yes, because you're commenting on *my* post, I get notified automatically. So it ignores that @.

Comment: ah! thx but would be maybe nice to keep it for other to be able to see explicitly who the reply is directed at

Comment: @zen • comments aren't supposed to be for extended conversations.  So such an @ use case was probably deemed unnecessary.  You can use the person's name without the @.  (*shrug*  Not my rule, just the general rule of StackOverflow as a Q&A forum.)